# @ElementCollection @CollectionTable in One to Many mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I am trying relationship between in JPA using Embedded annotation, but i am not able to run it successfully,

Here my Database sql Script is as follows,

```
create table TBL_COLLEGE(
   id integer primary key generated always as identity (start with 1000, increment by 5),
   name varchar(50)
)

create table TBL_COURSE(
   Id  integer primary key generated always as identity (start with 10, increment by 1),
   college_Id integer references TBL_COLLEGE,
   name varchar(50)
)
```

here is the code below for JPA,

```
@Embeddable
public class Course {
...
...
..
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="ID")
private Integer courseId;

@Column(name="NAME")
private String courseName;

@Column(name="COLLEGE_ID")
private Integer collegeId;
....
// getter and setter
}
```

Here is the College mapping,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TBL_COLLEGE")
public class College implements Serializable{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name="ID")
   private Integer collegeId;

   ...
   ..
   @ElementCollection(targetClass=Course.class,fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
   @CollectionTable(name="TBL_COURSE",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="COLLEGE_ID"))
   private Set<Course> course;
   ..
   // getter and setter
}
```

But if i try to persist College with Courses collection set,
it gives me an exception,

```
ERROR: HCANN000002: An assertion failure occurred (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate)
org.hibernate.annotations.common.AssertionFailure: Declaring class is not found in the inheritance state hierarchy: com.entities.Course

....
..
```

Can you please tell me whether my approach is wrong,
Or my understanding for @CollectionTable is still minimal,
Were i am going wrong

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because both of your tables have their own `ID` columns, Hibernate will want them to both be `@Entity` types.  `@Embeddables` do not have their own `ID`.  So, first step is to change `Course` to be `@Entity`, with corresponding `@TableName`, etc.

This leads to the second issue, which is that the collection of `Course` objects shouldn't be an `@ElementCollection`, it should be a [`@OneToMany`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#collections-mapping) entity collection, with a `@JoinColumn` specifying that `COLLEGE_ID` will is the foreign key from `TBL_COURSE`.

Finally, by having a collection of `Course` in `College`, as well as a `College` id in `Course`, you are implying that you want a [bidirectional association](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#collections-bidirectional).  Among other impacts of that, you should not have the `ID` of the college in `Course`.  You should simply have the `College` reference.  If you don't need to navigate from `Course`->`College`, you may want to remove that for now, until you've gained a better understanding of Hibernate's object mapping.

Comment: Not necessary to define OneToMany annotation etc.. It is enough to remove ID annotation from the embedded class. Of course GeneratedValue annotation should be removed also.

Comment: @asch - That is true, if you assume the OP didn't want Courses to be first class objects.  Given the tables as defined though, removing the ID annotation would cause problems.

Comment: Courses is already annotated as Embeddable, so it is not the Entity anyway (I guess you mean this by "the first class object")

Answer (score 0):

Though my approach is not proper but still it worked with some minor changes in the code,

first of all i dropped the table TBL_COURSE and created a new one, as follows,

```
create table TBL_COURSE(    
   college_Id integer references TBL_COLLEGE,
   name varchar(50)
)
```

here you can see i have removed the primary key, now there is only reference key and name,

Now in Course.java, i did following,

```
@Embeddable
public class Course {

// constuctor

@Column(name="NAME")
private String courseName; 
..
// setter getter
}
```

Here i have removed @Id annotation and id property,i have even removed the College_Id mapping,

and the rest of the code is same as present in College.java,

And it worked,

Waiting for the opinions

Comment: That's fine, as long as you want `Course` to have it's lifecycle defined by `College`, and not be a standalone entity.  You also won't be able to subclass `Course`, etc.

Answer (score -3):

You have to define the join about two pojo

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name=course table column id)
private Set<Course> course;
```